# d3js I can't render the links

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Thanks for reading. I am new to using the d3js library. I want to generate directed and ordered graphs on the x-axis and y-axis. For this I start from a json format where I specify the nodes and their location, as well as the links between them as you can see in the code.

However, I am not getting the links between the nodes rendered based on the json. Any help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>[D3] Force + Drag + Zoom</title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<style  id="compiled-css" type="text/css">
.node {
    fill:#ccc;
    stroke: #fff;
    stroke-width: 2px;
}
.node-active {
    stroke: #555;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
.link-active {
    stroke-opacity: 1;
}
line {
  stroke: rgb(212, 212, 212);
  stroke-width: 1px;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.overlay {
    fill: none;
    pointer-events: all;
}
.link{
    stroke: #ccc;
    stroke-width: 4px;
    }
svg {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid rgb(212, 212, 212);
}
</style>

<body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    resolution = 150,
    r = 15;

var graph = {
    "nodes":  [
        {"task": "1", "x": "150", "y": "450"},
        {"task": "2", "x": "300", "y": "150"},
        {"task": "3", "x": "450", "y": "300"}
        ],

    "links": [
        {"source": "1", "target": "2", "value": 3},
        {"source": "2", "target": "3", "value": 3},
        {"source": "1", "target": "3", "value": 3}
        ]
}

var margin = {
    top: -5,
    right: -5,
    bottom: -5,
    left: -5};

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-200)
    .linkDistance(50)
    .size([width + margin.left + margin.right, height + margin.top + margin.bottom]);

var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .origin(function(d) { return d; })
    .on('drag', dragged);


var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)
    .append("g");

var container = svg.append("g");

//force.links(graph.links)
  //  .start();

svg.selectAll('.vertical')
    .data(d3.range(1, width / resolution))
    .enter().append('line')
    .attr('class', 'vertical')
    .attr('x1', function(d) { return d * resolution; })
    .attr('y1', 0)
    .attr('x2', function(d) { return d * resolution; })
    .attr('y2', height);

svg.selectAll('.horizontal')
    .data(d3.range(1, height / resolution))
    .enter().append('line')
    .attr('class', 'horizontal')
    .attr('x1', 0)
    .attr('y1', function(d) { return d * resolution; })
    .attr('x2', width)
    .attr('y2', function(d) { return d * resolution; });

var link = container.append("g")
    .attr('class', 'link')
    .selectAll('.link')
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append('line')
    .attr("marker-end", "url(#end)")
    .style("stroke-width", function(d) {
        return Math.sqrt(d.value);
});

var node = container.append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .selectAll(".node")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append('circle')
    .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y; })
    .attr('r', r)
    .call(drag);

node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", function (d) {
    return d.weight * 2 + 12;
})
    .style("fill", function (d) { return color(1 / d.task); });

force.on("tick", function () {
    link.attr("x1", function (d) {
        return d.source.x;
    })
        .attr("y1", function (d) {
        return d.source.y;
    })
        .attr("x2", function (d) {
        return d.target.x;
    })
        .attr("y2", function (d) {
        return d.target.y;
    });

    /*node.attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });*/
});

var linkedByIndex = {};
graph.links.forEach(function (d) {
    linkedByIndex[d.source.index + "," + d.target.index] = 1;
});

function isConnected(a, b) {
    return linkedByIndex[a.index + "," + b.index] || linkedByIndex[b.index + "," + a.index];
}

node.on("mouseover", function (d) {

    node.classed("node-active", function (o) {
        thisOpacity = isConnected(d, o) ? true : false;
        this.setAttribute('fill-opacity', thisOpacity);
        return thisOpacity;
    });

    link.classed("link-active", function (o) {
        return o.source === d || o.target === d ? true : false;
    });

    d3.select(this).classed("node-active", true);
    d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attr("r", (d.weight * 2 + 12) * 1.5);
})

    .on("mouseout", function (d) {

    node.classed("node-active", false);
    link.classed("link-active", false);

    d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attr("r", d.weight * 2 + 12);
});

function dragged(d) {
  var x = d3.event.x,
      y = d3.event.y,
      gridX = round(Math.max(r, Math.min(width - r, x)), resolution),
      gridY = round(Math.max(r, Math.min(height - r, y)), resolution);

  d3.select(this).attr('cx', d.x = gridX).attr('cy', d.y = gridY);
}//

function round(p, n) {
  return p % n < n / 2 ? p - (p % n) : p + n - (p % n);
}

</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The links between your nodes are not showing up because you didn't specify the `x1`, `x2`, `y1`, and `y2` attributes, which are needed to display a line.

There is also a circle that's created incorrectly within a circle, and its attribute `r` is not correctly defined. The program throws:

> Error:  attribute r: Expected length, "NaN".

I'm not sure what that is for, so I commented it out. The following code should display the links now:

**Update**: Now the links will be displayed correctly when you drag!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>[D3] Force + Drag + Zoom</title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<style  id="compiled-css" type="text/css">
.node {
    fill:#ccc;
    stroke: #fff;
    stroke-width: 2px;
}
.node-active {
    stroke: #555;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
.link-active {
    stroke-opacity: 1;
}
line {
  stroke: rgb(212, 212, 212);
  stroke-width: 1px;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.overlay {
    fill: none;
    pointer-events: all;
}
.link{
    stroke: #ccc;
    stroke-width: 4px;
    }
svg {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid rgb(212, 212, 212);
}
</style>

<body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    resolution = 150,
    r = 15;

var graph = {
    "nodes":  [
        {"task": "1", "x": "150", "y": "450"},
        {"task": "2", "x": "300", "y": "150"},
        {"task": "3", "x": "450", "y": "300"}
        ],

    "links": [
        {"source": "1", "target": "2", "value": 3},
        {"source": "2", "target": "3", "value": 3},
        {"source": "1", "target": "3", "value": 3}
        ]
}

var margin = {
    top: -5,
    right: -5,
    bottom: -5,
    left: -5
};

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-200)
    .linkDistance(50)
    .size([width + margin.left + margin.right, height + margin.top + margin.bottom]);

var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .origin(function(d) { return d; })
    .on('drag', dragged);


var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)
    .append("g");

var container = svg.append("g");

//force.links(graph.links)
  //  .start();

svg.selectAll('.vertical')
    .data(d3.range(1, width / resolution))
    .enter().append('line')
    .attr('class', 'vertical')
    .attr('x1', function(d) { return d * resolution; })
    .attr('y1', 0)
    .attr('x2', function(d) { return d * resolution; })
    .attr('y2', height);

svg.selectAll('.horizontal')
    .data(d3.range(1, height / resolution))
    .enter().append('line')
    .attr('class', 'horizontal')
    .attr('x1', 0)
    .attr('y1', function(d) { return d * resolution; })
    .attr('x2', width)
    .attr('y2', function(d) { return d * resolution; });

var link = container.append("g")
    .attr('class', 'link')
    .selectAll('.link')
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append('line')
        .attr("data-source", function (d) {
          return d.source;
        })
        .attr("data-target", function (d) {
          return d.target;
        })
    .attr("x1", function (d) {
        for (let node of graph.nodes) {
            if (node.task === d.source)
                return node.x;
        }
    })
    .attr("x2", function (d) {
        for (let node of graph.nodes) {
            if (node.task === d.target)
                return node.x;
        }
    })
    .attr("y1", function (d) {
        for (let node of graph.nodes) {
            if (node.task === d.source)
                return node.y;
        }
    })
    .attr("y2", function (d) {
        for (let node of graph.nodes) {
            if (node.task === d.target)
                return node.y;
        }
    })
    .attr("marker-end", "url(#end)")
    .style("stroke-width", function(d) {
        return Math.sqrt(d.value);
});

var node = container.append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .selectAll(".node")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append('circle')
    .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y; })
    .attr('r', r)
    .call(drag);

/*
node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", function (d) {
    return d.weight * 2 + 12;
})
    .style("fill", function (d) { return color(1 / d.task); });

 */ // I'm not sure what this part is for

force.on("tick", function () {
    link.attr("x1", function (d) {

        return d.source.x;
    })
        .attr("y1", function (d) {
        return d.source.y;
    })
        .attr("x2", function (d) {
        return d.target.x;
    })
        .attr("y2", function (d) {
        return d.target.y;
    });

    /*node.attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });*/
});

var linkedByIndex = {};
graph.links.forEach(function (d) {
    linkedByIndex[d.source.index + "," + d.target.index] = 1;
});

function isConnected(a, b) {
    return linkedByIndex[a.index + "," + b.index] || linkedByIndex[b.index + "," + a.index];
}

node.on("mouseover", function (d) {

    node.classed("node-active", function (o) {
        thisOpacity = isConnected(d, o) ? true : false;
        this.setAttribute('fill-opacity', thisOpacity);
        return thisOpacity;
    });

    link.classed("link-active", function (o) {
        return o.source === d || o.target === d ? true : false;
    });

    d3.select(this).classed("node-active", true);
    d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attr("r", (d.weight * 2 + 12) * 1.5);
})

    .on("mouseout", function (d) {

    node.classed("node-active", false);
    link.classed("link-active", false);

    d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attr("r", d.weight * 2 + 12);
});

function dragged(d) {
  var x = d3.event.x,
      y = d3.event.y,
      gridX = round(Math.max(r, Math.min(width - r, x)), resolution),
      gridY = round(Math.max(r, Math.min(height - r, y)), resolution);

  d3.select(this).attr('cx', d.x = gridX).attr('cy', d.y = gridY);
  d3.selectAll(`[data-source='${d.task}']`).attr('x1', d.x).attr('y1', d.y);
  d3.selectAll(`[data-target='${d.task}']`).attr('x2', d.x).attr('y2', d.y);
}

function round(p, n) {
  return p % n < n / 2 ? p - (p % n) : p + n - (p % n);
}

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, your approach is a definite step forward. However, the problem persists that these are not updated when dragging the nodes.

Comment: @OsmelBordiésLópez Thanks for the follow-up. I updated the answer and it should work now :)

Comment: @OsmelBordiésLópez You're welcome! I'd like to inform you that if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: your proposal answers the question I posed, however, I still have some other issues to resolve in order to advance in the project I am working on. Considering that I am trying to represent directed graphs, I must represent the arrowheads (link), as well as the labels corresponding to the links and the nodes (node). Work to do! :-D

Comment: @OsmelBordiésLópez I'm glad that I helped you and good luck with your project! Feel free to post a new question and follow up with me on this post if you run into any additional issues

Comment: I have added a new post. You might want to check it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67249054/locating-the-nodes-according-to-the-coordinates-in-the-json/67250519?noredirect=1#comment1189

Comment: I have added a new post. You might want to check it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67468111/d3js-moving-the-labels-next-to-the-nodes