# Locating the nodes according to the coordinates in the json

Tags: d3.js, graph, location, nodes, directed-graph

I am trying to make the nodes of the directed network appear to be located at the coordinates reflected in the json document when the page is started. However, the actual code recalculates the node positions, which does not fit the requirements of my application . Any help?

MAIN CODE

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style type="text/css">
    .node {}

    .link { 
        stroke: #999; 
        stroke-opacity: .6; 
        stroke-width: 1px; 
        }
    line {
        stroke: rgb(212, 212, 212);
        stroke-width: 1px;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges; 
        }
    svg { 
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: 1px solid rgb(212, 212, 212);
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <svg width="960" height="600"></svg>

    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection-multi.v1.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    resolution = 150,
    r = 15;

    var colors = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

    var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height"),
    node,
    link;

    svg.selectAll('.vertical')
    .data(d3.range(1, width / resolution))
    .enter().append('line')
    .attr('class', 'vertical')
    .attr('x1', function(d) { return d * resolution; })
    .attr('y1', 0)
    .attr('x2', function(d) { return d * resolution; })
    .attr('y2', height);

    svg.selectAll('.horizontal')
    .data(d3.range(1, height / resolution))
    .enter().append('line')
    .attr('class', 'horizontal')
    .attr('x1', 0)
    .attr('y1', function(d) { return d * resolution; })
     .attr('x2', width)
    .attr('y2', function(d) { return d * resolution; });

    svg.append('defs').append('marker')
    .attrs({'id':'arrowhead',
        'viewBox':'-0 -5 10 10',
        'refX':13,
        'refY':0,
        'orient':'auto',
        'markerWidth':13,
        'markerHeight':13,
        'xoverflow':'visible'})
    .append('svg:path')
    .attr('d', 'M 0,-5 L 10 ,0 L 0,5')
    .attr('fill', '#999')
    .style('stroke','none');

    var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function (d) {return d.id;}).distance(150).strength(1))
    //.force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    //.force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

    d3.json("graph.json", function (error, graph) {
    if (error) throw error;
    update(graph.links, graph.nodes);
    })

    function update(links, nodes) {
    link = svg.selectAll(".link")
        .data(links)
        .enter()
        .append("line")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr('marker-end','url(#arrowhead)')

    link.append("title")
        .text(function (d) {return d.type;});

    edgepaths = svg.selectAll(".edgepath")
        .data(links)
        .enter()
        .append('path')
        .attrs({
            'class': 'edgepath',
            'fill-opacity': 0,
            'stroke-opacity': 0,
            'id': function (d, i) {return 'edgepath' + d.type}
        })
        .style("pointer-events", "none");

    edgelabels = svg.selectAll(".edgelabel")
        .data(links)
        .enter()
        .append('text')
        .style("pointer-events", "none")
        .attrs({
            'class': 'edgelabel',
            'id': function (d, i) {return 'edgelabel' + i},
            'font-size': 15,
            'fill': '#000'
        });

    edgelabels.append('textPath')
        .attr('xlink:href', function (d, i) {return '#edgepath' + i})
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .style("pointer-events", "none")
        .attr("startOffset", "50%")
        .text(function (d) {return d.type});

    node = svg.selectAll(".node")
        .data(nodes)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y; })
        .call(d3.drag()
                .on("start", dragstarted)
                .on("drag", dragged)
                //.on("end", dragended)
        );

    node.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 15)
        .style("fill", function (d, i) {return colors(i);})

    node.append("title")
        .text(function (d) {return d.social;});

    node.append("text")
        .attr("dy", -3)
        .text(function (d) {return d.name+":"+d.social;});

    simulation
        .nodes(nodes)
        .on("tick", ticked);

    simulation.force("link")
        .links(links);
    }

    function ticked() {
    link
        .attr("x1", function (d) {return d.source.x;})
        .attr("y1", function (d) {return d.source.y;})
        .attr("x2", function (d) {return d.target.x;})
        .attr("y2", function (d) {return d.target.y;});

    node
        .attr("transform", function (d) {return "translate(" + d.x + ", " + d.y + ")";});

    edgepaths.attr('d', function (d) {
        return 'M ' + d.source.x + ' ' + d.source.y + ' L ' + d.target.x + ' ' + d.target.y;
    });
    }

    function dragstarted(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(1.0).restart()
    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
    }

    function dragged(d) {
    d.fx = d3.event.x;
    d.fy = d3.event.y;

    gridX = round(Math.max(r, Math.min(width - r, d.fx)), resolution);
    gridY = round(Math.max(r, Math.min(height - r, d.fy)), resolution);

    d3.select(this).attr('cx', d.fx = gridX).attr('cy', d.fy = gridY);


    }

    function round(p, n) {
    return p % n < n / 2 ? p - (p % n) : p + n - (p % n);
    }

    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

> Here I attach the data of the json document that hosts the directed
> graph data:

```
    {
     "nodes": [
    {
      "name": "1",
      "label": "1",
      "social": "I",
      "id": 1,
      "x": 150, 
      "y": 450
    },
    {
      "name": "2",
      "label": "2",
      "social": "G",
      "id": 1,
      "x": 300, 
      "y": 150
    },
    {
      "name": "3",
      "label": "3",
      "social": "T",
      "id": 1,
      "x": 450, 
      "y": 300
    }
    ],
    "links": [
    {
      "source": 1,
      "target": 2,
      "type": "N:1"
    },
    {
      "source": 2,
      "target": 3,
      "type": "1:N"
    }
    ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will not work:

```
node = svg.selectAll(".node")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x; })
  .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y; })
  ...
```

replace it with:

```
node = svg.selectAll(".node")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .classed('node', true)
  .attr('transform', d => `translate(${d.x},${d.y})`)
  ...
```

**<g>** element does not have **cx** and **cy** attributes, it uses transform instead. Also, d3 **classed** routine is more usable than `attr('class')`.

UPD: The newly created links are missing their initial coordinates:

```
link = svg.selectAll(".link")
  .data(links)
  .enter()
  .append("line")
  .classed("link", true)
  .attr('marker-end','url(#arrowhead)')
  .attr("x1", d => d.source.x)
  .attr("x2", d => d.target.x)
  .attr("y1", d => d.source.y)
  .attr("y1", d => d.target.y)
```

Comment: I have used your proposal but the nodes are still not rendered according to the coordinates defined in the json. The nodes are "transformed" when the page loads.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the sentence: __The nodes are "transformed" when the page loads__ ... Can you post some screenshots or describe the broblem more precisely?

Comment: What is happening is that when the page is loaded, the nodes are placed in the locations defined in the graph.json document. However, the edges are initially placed in a "random" place (see figure https://imgur.com/wBlwT2l) and then, the code relocates the nodes where the edges have been placed. In my case, the edges should be placed according to the nodes.

Comment: OK, I see. But it's a different problem. You need to position your links correctly.

Comment: No, it doesn't work... something similar is happening (https://imgur.com/vqAPelX)

Comment: Please provide a fiddle or a sandbox

Comment: Your fiddle seems to be working very well. Is there a problem?

Comment: Actually, I have put you a code that corresponds to a different problem than the one referred to in the post. It corresponds to version v3 of the d3 library, where the problem of the post is solved, but not that of the labels.

Comment: The code corresponding to the current post is this: https://jsfiddle.net/obordies25/c0erbdL7/3/
But I don't know how to link the json document :-(

Comment: You want to add labels to the nodes?

Comment: I see why there are no texts in the fiddle ( https://jsfiddle.net/obordies25/L76yboz9/6 ). You append `<circle>` after `enter()`, and then trying to append `<text>` under the `<circle>`. __It cannot work__.  You should append `<g>` on enter, and then, you can append both `<circle>` and `<text>` under `<g>`. Please rewrite your code very carefully, remove redundant parts, make sure it works __exactly__ the way I described.

Comment: I believe I have made the suggested modifications. I have managed to insert and position the text, as well as group nodes and text, but it still doesn't work. I can move the nodes but not the text. See https://jsfiddle.net/obordies25/L76yboz9/11/.

Comment: I see the problem with text. Can you please post another question with this specific problem and I will try to solve it. Since we have solved the problem with links, please mark my answer as correct.

Comment: Michael Rovinsky, new post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67468111/d3js-moving-the-labels-next-to-the-nodes