# d3js Moving the labels next to the nodes

Tags: d3.js, label, nodes, d3-force-directed

I am developing a project on pattern representation through graphs. I have come to retrieve the data from a json to generate the graphs and locate the labels associated with the nodes (I would also like to locate the labels corresponding to the links). However, when moving the nodes, I am unable to move the labels. Any help? [See the code here](http://jsfiddle.net/obordies25/L76yboz9/11):

```js
var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    resolution = 150,
    r = 15;

var graph = {
    "nodes":  [
        {"task": "1", "label": "1", "social": "I", "id": 1, "x": 150, "y": 450},
        {"task": "2", "label": "2", "social": "G", "id": 2, "x": 300, "y": 150},
        {"task": "3", "label": "3", "social": "T", "id": 3, "x": 450, "y": 300}
        ],

    "links": [
        {"source": "1", "target": "2", "type": "N:1"},
        {"source": "2", "target": "3", "type": "1:N"},
        {"source": "1", "target": "3", "type": "1:1"}
        ]
}

var margin = {
    top: -5,
    right: -5,
    bottom: -5,
    left: -5
};

var colors = d3.scale.category20();

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height);

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-200)
    .linkDistance(50)
    .size([width + margin.left + margin.right, height + margin.top + margin.bottom])
    .nodes(graph.nodes);

var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .origin(function(d) { return d; })
    .on('drag', dragged);

svg.selectAll('.vertical')
    .data(d3.range(1, width / resolution))
    .enter().append('line')
    .attr('class', 'vertical')
    .attr('x1', function(d) { return d * resolution; })
    .attr('y1', 0)
    .attr('x2', function(d) { return d * resolution; })
    .attr('y2', height);

svg.selectAll('.horizontal')
    .data(d3.range(1, height / resolution))
    .enter().append('line')
    .attr('class', 'horizontal')
    .attr('x1', 0)
    .attr('y1', function(d) { return d * resolution; })
    .attr('x2', width)
    .attr('y2', function(d) { return d * resolution; });

svg.append('defs').append('marker')
    .attr({'id':'arrowhead',
        'viewBox':'-0 -5 10 10',
        'refX':25,
        'refY':0,
        'orient':'auto',
        'markerWidth':5,
        'markerHeight':5,
        'xoverflow':'visible'})
    .append('svg:path')
    .attr('d', 'M 0,-5 L 10 ,0 L 0,5')
    .attr('fill', '#777')
    .style('stroke','none');


var link = svg.selectAll("svg.link")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr('marker-end','url(#arrowhead)')

    .attr("data-source", function (d) {
          return d.source;
        })
    .attr("data-target", function (d) {
          return d.target;
        })
    .attr("x1", function (d) {
        for (let node of graph.nodes) {
            if (node.task === d.source)
                return node.x;
        }
    })
    .attr("x2", function (d) {
        for (let node of graph.nodes) {
            if (node.task === d.target)
                return node.x;
        }
    })
    .attr("y1", function (d) {
        for (let node of graph.nodes) {
            if (node.task === d.source)
                return node.y;
        }
    })
    .attr("y2", function (d) {
        for (let node of graph.nodes) {
            if (node.task === d.target)
                return node.y;
        }
    })
    .style("stroke-width", function(d) {
        return Math.sqrt(d.value);
});

var node = svg.selectAll("svg.node")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append('g');

node.append("circle")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y; })
    .attr('r', r)
    .call(drag);//
    
//text element
node.append("title")
    .text(function (d) {return d.social});

node.append("text")
    //.attr("dx", )
    //.attr("dy", 6)
    .attr("class", "font")
    .attr('dx', function(d) { return d.x-6; })
    .attr('dy', function(d) { return d.y+6; })
    .text(function(d) { return d.social; });

force.on("tick", function () {
    link.attr("x1", function (d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function (d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function (d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function (d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

});

function dragged(d) {
  var x = d3.event.x,
      y = d3.event.y,

      gridX = round(Math.max(r, Math.min(width - r, x)), resolution),
      gridY = round(Math.max(r, Math.min(height - r, y)), resolution);

      d3.select(this).attr('cx', d.x = gridX).attr('cy', d.y = gridY);
      d3.select(this).attr('dx', d.x = gridX).attr('dy', d.y = gridY);

      d3.selectAll(`[data-source='${d.task}']`).attr('x1', d.x).attr('y1', d.y);
      d3.selectAll(`[data-target='${d.task}']`).attr('x2', d.x).attr('y2', d.y);
}

function round(p, n) {
  return p % n < n / 2 ? p - (p % n) : p + n - (p % n);
}
```

```css
.node {
    fill:#ccc;
    stroke: #fff;
    stroke-width: 2px;
}
.node-active {
    stroke: #555;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
link-active {
    stroke: #555;
    stroke-opacity: 5;
}
line {
  stroke: rgb(212, 212, 212);
  stroke-width: 1px;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.overlay {
    fill: none;
    pointer-events: all;
}
.link{
    stroke: #ccc;
    stroke-width: 2px;
    }
svg {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid rgb(212, 212, 212);
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>[D3]</title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  
  <body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an identification attribute to `<circle>` and `<text>` elements:

```
...attr('node-id', d => d.social)
```

Move the text along with the circle:

```
d3.select(`text[node-id='${d.social}']`).attr('dx', d.x).attr('dy', d.y)
```

Use text-anchor and alignment-baseline for `<text>` labels instead of offsets (+6/-6):

```
...attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
  .attr('alignment-baseline', 'middle')
  .attr('dx', function(d) { return d.x; })
  .attr('dy', function(d) { return d.y; })
```

I also enlarged the `<circle>`s to make them easy to drag...

```js
var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    resolution = 150,
    r = 15;

var graph = {
    "nodes":  [
        {"task": "1", "label": "1", "social": "I", "id": 1, "x": 150, "y": 450},
        {"task": "2", "label": "2", "social": "G", "id": 2, "x": 300, "y": 150},
        {"task": "3", "label": "3", "social": "T", "id": 3, "x": 450, "y": 300}
        ],

    "links": [
        {"source": "1", "target": "2", "type": "N:1"},
        {"source": "2", "target": "3", "type": "1:N"},
        {"source": "1", "target": "3", "type": "1:1"}
        ]
}

var margin = {
    top: -5,
    right: -5,
    bottom: -5,
    left: -5
};

var colors = d3.scale.category20();

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height);

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-200)
    .linkDistance(50)
    .size([width + margin.left + margin.right, height + margin.top + margin.bottom])
    .nodes(graph.nodes);

var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .origin(function(d) { return d; })
    .on('drag', dragged);

svg.selectAll('.vertical')
    .data(d3.range(1, width / resolution))
    .enter().append('line')
    .attr('class', 'vertical')
    .attr('x1', function(d) { return d * resolution; })
    .attr('y1', 0)
    .attr('x2', function(d) { return d * resolution; })
    .attr('y2', height);

svg.selectAll('.horizontal')
    .data(d3.range(1, height / resolution))
    .enter().append('line')
    .attr('class', 'horizontal')
    .attr('x1', 0)
    .attr('y1', function(d) { return d * resolution; })
    .attr('x2', width)
    .attr('y2', function(d) { return d * resolution; });

svg.append('defs').append('marker')
    .attr({'id':'arrowhead',
        'viewBox':'-0 -5 10 10',
        'refX':40,
        'refY':0,
        'orient':'auto',
        'markerWidth':5,
        'markerHeight':5,
        'xoverflow':'visible'})
    .append('svg:path')
    .attr('d', 'M 0,-5 L 10 ,0 L 0,5')
    .attr('fill', '#777')
    .style('stroke','none');


var link = svg.selectAll("svg.link")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr('marker-end','url(#arrowhead)')

    .attr("data-source", function (d) {
          return d.source;
        })
    .attr("data-target", function (d) {
          return d.target;
        })
    .attr("x1", function (d) {
        for (let node of graph.nodes) {
            if (node.task === d.source)
                return node.x;
        }
    })
    .attr("x2", function (d) {
        for (let node of graph.nodes) {
            if (node.task === d.target)
                return node.x;
        }
    })
    .attr("y1", function (d) {
        for (let node of graph.nodes) {
            if (node.task === d.source)
                return node.y;
        }
    })
    .attr("y2", function (d) {
        for (let node of graph.nodes) {
            if (node.task === d.target)
                return node.y;
        }
    })
    .style("stroke-width", function(d) {
        return Math.sqrt(d.value);
});

var node = svg.selectAll("svg.node")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append('g');

node.append("circle")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr('node-id', d => d.social)
    .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y; })
    .attr('r', r * 2)
    .call(drag);//
    
node.append("text")
    .attr("class", "label")
    .attr('node-id', d => d.social)
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .attr('alignment-baseline', 'middle')
    .attr('dx', function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr('dy', function(d) { return d.y; })
    .text(function(d) { return d.social; });

force.on("tick", function () {
    link.attr("x1", function (d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function (d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function (d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function (d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

});

function dragged(d) {
  var x = d3.event.x,
      y = d3.event.y,

      gridX = round(Math.max(r, Math.min(width - r, x)), resolution),
      gridY = round(Math.max(r, Math.min(height - r, y)), resolution);

      d3.select(this).attr('cx', d.x = gridX).attr('cy', d.y = gridY);
      d3.select(this).attr('dx', d.x = gridX).attr('dy', d.y = gridY);

      d3.selectAll(`[data-source='${d.task}']`).attr('x1', d.x).attr('y1', d.y);
      d3.selectAll(`[data-target='${d.task}']`).attr('x2', d.x).attr('y2', d.y);
      d3.select(`text[node-id='${d.social}']`).attr('dx', d.x).attr('dy', d.y)
}

function round(p, n) {
  return p % n < n / 2 ? p - (p % n) : p + n - (p % n);
}
```

```css
.node {
    fill:#ccc;
    stroke: #fff;
    stroke-width: 2px;
}
.node-active {
    stroke: #555;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
link-active {
    stroke: #555;
    stroke-opacity: 5;
}
line {
  stroke: rgb(212, 212, 212);
  stroke-width: 1px;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.overlay {
    fill: none;
    pointer-events: all;
}
.link{
    stroke: #ccc;
    stroke-width: 2px;
    }
svg {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid rgb(212, 212, 212);
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>[D3]</title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  
  <body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
```